# Error "Multiple markers at this line, Missing semicolon" in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

To work on photo swipe in phonegap i downloaded many source code from github, but in jquery.1.10.1.min.js file i'm getting "Multiple markers at this line
    - Missing semicolon" error, i manually tried to add ";" but still getting the same error, not only for this source code but for all which has jquery file. 
github link: https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper. why this happens only for jquery please help me.

Comment: If you comment out jquery, do you get a different syntax error?

Comment: i manually added ";" where ever the alert message tells, but dont know how to solve this error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from any[]" @TedHopp

Comment: I mean, if you (temporarily) eliminate loading jquery. The idea is to test whether the problem is really in jquery (very unlikely) or that there's a syntax error or something in the surrounding script.